# javascript - store regEx in a set object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I made a simple crawler using `simplecrawler` :D

Its constructor has a set object which hold visited URLs:

```
this.visited = new Set();
```

Any invalid URL will be added there:

```
this.visited.add(url);
```

Currently, when new url is added in the queue I check if it is visited:

```
if (this.visited.has(newURL))
```

Can I have regEx in this set object to block url from specific site to be used as below?

```
// to block www.xxx.com/123, www.xxx.com/456, www.xxx.com/789
this.visited.add('/www\.xxx\.com\/\d/g');

if (this.visited.has(givenURL))
  // do not visit
else
  // visit
```

If this can be done, what would be the best way to get this done?

Comment: The way I would do it, is probably by getting the domain name from url using regex and then adding it to the Set. Then, whenever you do check of the visited URL, instead of full URL, you can check if the domain was visited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over the Set and check if a URL matches the item in the set:

```
this.visited = new Set();
var BreakException = {};
this.visited.add('www\\.xxx\\.com/\\d+');
this.visited.add('www.xxx.com/123')
try {
    this.visited.forEach(function(x) {
        if ('www.xxx.com/123'.match(new RegExp(x))) {
            var visited = true;
            throw BreakException;
        }
    });
} catch (e) {
    // do not visit
}
if (visited) {
    // visit
}
```

Pay attention on the URL I added to the set. The one you used in the question wouldn't work.

You have to throw an exception to break the loop since `Array.forEach` doesn't support `break;`.